# Don't show delete checkbox for nested form object if not persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with nested attributes. I'm building a nested object in controller to show at least one nested input.

```
def new
  @question = Question.new
  @question.attachments.build
end
```

I'm also rendering a delete checkbox to delete nested objects. But I don't want to show delete checkbox for a nested object that's built but not created.

```
=form_for @question do |f|
  .form-group
    =f.text_area :body

  = f.fields_for :attachments do |a|
    .form-group
      = a.label :file
      = a.file_field :file
      = a.check_box '_destroy'

  = f.submit
```

How can I hide a delete checkbox for not persisted objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
= a.check_box '_destroy' if a.object.persisted?
```